# Solr - Exception Handling

Tags: solr, exception

I am using Solr(On Tomcat server) with Webservices. When the end user pass the Solr query url, the request goes through the webservice and render back the result in browser.
In case of exception, I am getting the HTTP ERROR 500 followed by the trace log in browser. I do not want end user to see the trace log but wanted to display a custom error message in the browser.

Any idea on how can I achieve this ?

**Code snippet I am using**

```
private Integer determineStart(final String start) throws DQSException {
        Integer intValue = null;
        try{
            intValue = Integer.valueOf(start) ;
            return intValue;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            throw new DQSException(
                    "Start should be a Numeric value >= 0");
        }
    }
```

**Customized Exception**

```
public class DQSException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7669894738044609438L;

    public DQSException(String message, Throwable e) {
        super(message,e);
    }

    public DQSException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

**Exception in the Browser**

HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /dqs/query/hrportal/select. Reason: Server Error
Caused by: com.fmr.ctg.hr.hrdh.dqs.execptions.DQSException: Start should be a Numeric value >= 0
    at com.fmr.ctg.hr.hrdh.dqs.rest.QueryService.determineStart(QueryService.java:245)
    at com.fmr.ctg.hr.hrdh.dqs.rest.QueryService.selectAll(QueryService.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

```
    ...
    ...
```

**Expected Error Message in Browser without any stack trace logs:**

Start should be a Numeric value >= 0

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: please let us know what you have thought of.

Comment: I tried adding the following piece of code in web.xml. But no luck. Not sure whether it make sense to do in this way!

<error-page>
 <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
 <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

error.jsp
---------
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" contentType="text/plain"%>
Message:
<%=exception.getMessage()%>
StackTrace:
<%
 StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
 PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
 exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
 out.println(stringWriter);
%>

Answer (score 0):

You can easily put a try-catch block round your code and return a custom error message.

Check out my webservice written in C# for an idea:

http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/07/web-service-to-query-solr-rest.html

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have added my code snippet to convey what exactly I needed.